# jQuery get table header name of clicked cell with id

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I have a table, and in that table I have values with `id="edit"`. Now, what I want is to get the header name of the corresponding column when I click on any of the cells. What I have so far, based on a previous question asked is:

```
$('body').on('click', 'td#edit', function() {  
    var th = $('this').closest('th').eq($('th').val());
    alert(th);        // returns [object Object]
    .........................
}
```

Can you help me out with this?

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable" class="myTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>JobNo</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>JobDate</th>
        <th>Warranty</th>
        <th>RepairStatus</th>
        <th>POP</th>
        <th>DOA</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>SN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="check">
            <input type="checkbox" value="12345">
        </td>
        <td class="edit">
            <b>12345</b>
        </td>
        <td class="edit">gdsgasdfasfasdfa</td>
        <td class="edit">2011-01-21</td>
        <td class="edit">TRUE</td>
        <td class="edit">RP</td>
        <td class="edit">FALSE</td>
        <td class="edit">0</td>
        <td class="edit">5152342</td>
        <td class="edit">66665464</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should not have `values` with `id=edit` the id should be unique

Comment: Are you using the same id multiple time? You wrote you have value*s* with `id="edit"`. IDs should be unique

Comment: what is the `HTML` markup..??

Comment: 'id' should be unique always. You cant give id="edit" to all td.

Comment: Whether it is a class or id, it does not solve my problem. That was not the question i asked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) loop in ancestors up the `DOM` tree and th is not parent of td so closest is not right option. First of all use class if you are having same id for more than one elements. Secondly use index() to find the corresponding `th` of `td`. For being specific assign `id` to parent table so that the script does not operate on other `tables / td` on page.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XRRhB/)**

*Html*

```
<table id="tbl1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>heading 1</th>
        <th>heading 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td class="edit">row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td class="edit">row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#tbl1').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var th = $('#tbl1 th').eq($(this).index());
    alert(th.text()); // returns text of respective header
});
```

Comment: This works, but returns wrong header, and always the same one. I will update my question with the HTML markup.

Comment: This works. But i want to pester you with one more addition :) Since the table is loaded with Ajax i need the `$('body').on('click', '.edit', function() {` to register the events correctly. When i put your code inside this function  it loops +1 every time. So when i click the first time i get `JobNo` , 2nd time i get `JobNo \n JobNo` and so on....how can i fix that?

Comment: Yes, just give me a second to figure it out , since i haven't used jsfiddle before ;)

Comment: You need to delegate event to element that is present at the time on is used to bind, since your table does not exists it does not bind, you can bind to closest parent or document or document.body, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/cFWtu/2/

Comment: I can swear i tried this and it didn't work :| Probably made some stupid error...Anyway, thank you very much for your help, this solves the problem! :))

Comment: Beautiful. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work if some of the cells use colspan. In my table I had a cell with colspan = "3", meaning the 'index' of the cell behind it, is off by 2

Answer (score 1):

For this markup

```
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Header One</th>
        <th>Header Two</th>
        <th>Header Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">One</td>
        <td class="edit">Two</td>
        <td class="edit">Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">One</td>
        <td class="edit">Two</td>
        <td class="edit">Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use this jQuery code:

```
$(".mytable").on('click', 'td.edit', function(e) {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    console.log(table.find('.header th').eq(index).text());  // returns the header text  
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7qXm8/