# Table: click in row then show me the column id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a very simple table. When i click in a row does i become the id from the clicked column. Any ideas?

```
<table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th id="address">Address</th>
           <th id="country">Country</th>
           <th id="number">number</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>address1</td>
           <td>country1</td>
           <td>number1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>address2</td>
           <td>country2</td>
           <td>number2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>address3</td>
           <td>country3</td>
           <td>number3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example:

Click on Country2: country(column id)
Click on Number3: number(column id)

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert('clicked in row, but which column?');
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get table header name of clicked cell with id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494998/jquery-get-table-header-name-of-clicked-cell-with-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check the index of the `td` with respect row and then find the respected column `th` id using [`eq()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiE9rvawr_TAhXGRY8KHYhZBkIQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feq%2F&usg=AFQjCNF421AWRe2A4OnKM21N9XQV5cUFMA&sig2=MleKlSQJVyrmbtmfHfJsAg) function of jquery

```js
$('tr td').click(function(){
var a = $(this).index();
var id = $('tr th').eq(a).attr('id')
console.log(id);


})
```

```css
table ,tr,td{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="address">Address</th>
    <th id="country">Country</th>
    <th id="number">number</th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>address1</td>
        <td>country1</td>
        <td>number1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>address2</td>
        <td>country2</td>
        <td>number2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>address3</td>
        <td>country3</td>
        <td>number3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Only correct answer here in my opinion, not sure why everyone else is returning the row index

Comment: @Pete check also my answer

Comment: @Pete .its not a row index.its a column index respected with `row` .it useful to find the respected column id in `th`

Comment: @prasad I know yours is doing column index, I was just wondering why everyone else was doing a row index - half of them have changed it now

Answer (score 0):

Get the row index using `$(this).index() + 1`:

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  alert('You clicked on row '+ ($(this).index() + 1 ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` . Index start with 0 so add 1 .

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
      var row = $(this).index() + 1;  // Index start with 0 so add 1
      alert(row);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="address">Address</th>
      <th id="country">Country</th>
      <th id="number">number</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>address1</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>number1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>address2</td>
          <td>country2</td>
          <td>number2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>address3</td>
          <td>country3</td>
          <td>number3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $table = $('#myTable'),
    $th = $table.find('thead tr th');

$table.find('tbody tr').on('click', 'td', function () {
  console.log($th[$(this).index()].id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th id="address">Address</th>
         <th id="country">Country</th>
         <th id="number">number</th>
      </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>address1</td>
         <td>country1</td>
         <td>number1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>address2</td>
         <td>country2</td>
         <td>number2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>address3</td>
         <td>country3</td>
         <td>number3</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful.

Html:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">

        <tr>
          <th id="address">Address</th>
          <th id="country">Country</th>
          <th id="number">number</th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>address1</td>
              <td>country1</td>
              <td>number1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>address2</td>
              <td>country2</td>
              <td>number2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>address3</td>
              <td>country3</td>
              <td>number3</td>
            </tr>

    </table>
     </body>


    </html>
```

Script:

```
 <script>
        $('#myTable tbody').on('click','td', function () {
            var row = $(this).index() ;  
            alert(row);
        });
    </script>
```

specify the 'td' in the script function. Doing this you will get the column id of the selected column in particular row.